# Problem involving Monte Carlo Integration

Tags: monte-carlo, exponential-distribution, integral, score-function

Given the probability density function (p.d.f.) of an exponential distribution, i.e., $$f_{\theta}(x) = \frac{1}{\theta}\, e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}, \; \; \; 0 < x < \infty; \; \; \theta > 0.$$

Also, given the score function of the above-mentioned p.d.f., i.e., $$u_{\theta} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \, log_e(f_{\theta}(x)) = - \frac{1}{\theta} + \frac{x}{\theta^2}.$$

Then how do I evaluate the following expression : 
$$\frac{\int \bigg( - \frac{1}{\theta} + \frac{x}{\theta^2} \bigg) f_{\theta}^2(x) \;e^{\alpha f_{\theta}(x)} \; dx}{\int f_{\theta}^2(x) \;e^{\alpha f_{\theta}(x)} \; dx}, \; \; \alpha \in \mathcal{R}; \; \; \mathcal{R}\; \textrm{is the real number line.}$$

(In the above expression, $f_{\theta}(x)$ is replaced by the p.d.f. of the exponential distribution, which has been mentioned at first.)

If we use **Monte Carlo Integration** method, then what suitable probability density function (some, $g_{\theta}(x)$) should we use here to solve the above-mentioned expression ?

Comment: Is $\theta$ known? The pdf $g$ need not be a function of $\theta$. Have you tried any pdfs so far? If yes, why haven't they worked? My instinct would be to try $f_{\theta}(x)$ itself first.

Comment: There's more than one way to integrate using Monte Carlo so it's not 100% clear what role $g$ is to play. Are you talking about $g$ being a majorizing function? Are you talking about $g$ in importance sampling or a VEGAS algorithm? If none of those, what is $g$ being used to do?

Comment: @Greenparker: I would second your suggestion to use $f_\theta$ or $f_\theta^2$ which is also an exponential distribution as the importance function.